# Why is milliseconds in timespan not increasing between two DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, time, timestamp

I have this simple bit of code:

```
//LastUpdate = DateTime.Npw
//These two lines occur every frame
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now - data.LastUpdate;
Debug.Log(timeSpan.Milliseconds);
```

But the result of this is showing milliseconds not really increasing, it fluctuates between 100 to 900 ms. It should be ever increasing in size since, the time past is increasing.

I have checked that LastUpdate does not change, so that isn't the cause.

I guess i am misunderstanding how timespan works. I am trying to get milliseconds that has passed between LastUpdate and `now` of the current frame.

Am i using it wrong ? I don't understand the issue.

Comment: You might want to switch to using `StopWatch` as it's better suited for measuring time spans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [TimeSpan docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx):

`.Milliseconds` (emphasis mine):

> Gets the milliseconds **component** of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure.

You want to use `.TotalMilliseconds`:

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional milliseconds.

Comment: Oops. Well just wasted an hour because of that one tiny mistake.
Thanks

Comment: @WDKU No worries :) I also went down that path a long time ago.